# Install mysqlclient for Python 3.6 on a Raspbian system

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian, python-3.6

I am trying to install mysqlclient for Python 3.6 following the Readme on their GibHub (https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/README.md).
When I try to import mysqlclient in my Python script, it says that Python couldn't find this library.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import MySQLdb
```

mysqlclient is just a fork of MySQLdb

Comment: I reinstalled it with the source package instead of pip and now its working

Comment: @no0by5 I'm glad it works, from your question, I thought you were importing by the wrong library name. Anyway, cheers man

Comment: That was also a problem. I wasn't sure, what the library name is, so I always had to test several names. Thank you!